# What is kafka user in apache kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka user is same as kafka "producer"? Or is it different.I am searching regarding kafka Access Control List in which we give access to user on topic. But i am confused what is user.

Answer (score 1):

In Kafka, ACLs are defined on Principals. Principal are somewhat analogous to users.

As per the [documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_authz):

> Kafka acls are defined in the general format of "Principal P is
>   [Allowed/Denied] Operation O From Host H On Resource R".

A Principal has the format `TYPE:NAME`. For example `User:Alice`.

Kafka creates a Principal for each connection (that can be customized via `principal.builder.class`) depending on the protocol used.

By default:

- with Plaintext: all connections will have the same principal: `User:Anonymous`
- with SSL: the Principal will be using this format `User:"CN=Duke, OU=JavaSoft, O=Sun Microsystems, C=US"`
- with SASL: the Principal is the username, eg: `User:Alice`

For example, an ACL granting Bob DESCRIBE and WRITE on topic called `test-topic`:

```
bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:Bob --producer --topic test-topic
```

Here `producer` is just a shortcut to add all necessary Operations for producing messages: DESCRIBE and WRITE. See http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_authz_cli

Comment: So user is not like user on server?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "user on server".

Comment: Like we log on to particular address by using user and password... so this is not same as kafka user

Comment: No this is not the same. You need a Principal (Kafka user) for ACLs.