# How to delete a user in Apache Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to delete a Kafka user.

Is this something that can be achieved?

Honestly, im not even sure im actually understanding the concept of Kafka users.
I started by reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49425709/what-is-kafka-user-in-apache-kafka), but im not being able to easily extract any conclusion.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka user per say it's just the sum of its permissions, there is no "real" kafka user object in kafka.

Let's say that the "kafka" saves just the definitions of authorisations the user/principle possess.

You can remove the principle permissions, with an adequate command, for example kafka-acls.sh with the --remove parameter.

Comment: If I understood correctly, one can add a user by using kafka-config command. Bu how can I remove that user? Is it enough to use "kafka-acls.sh --remove ..." ?

Answer (score 3):

You can remove SCRAM password and/or quota config from kafka with a command like:

```
kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --alter --delete-config "SCRAM-SHA-256" --entity-type users --entity-name USERNAME
```

And describe existing user configs with:

```
kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --describe --entity-type users
```